# Pushing Rect-Datepicker date State to Another React Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-dom, react-datepicker

I am having a problem finding a way i can reliably store the state of the date from react-datepicker, and exporting that state to another component via URL parameter.

To give some context, I have two components. A Picker.JS component containing the react-datepicker calendar, and a separate Component called "DelayGuage", which dynamically draws a google charts guage using an API call. The only problem is, this API call has a dynamic parameter known as {date}, and this {date} parameter MUST come from the previously selected datepicker date.

Here is my DatePicker code Below. The issue I am having is that I keep getting
"Uncaught TypeError: event.target is undefined" when I attempt to call handleSubmit() after the calendar date is selected (onSelect).

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import {Link, useNavigate} from "react-router-dom"

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

// CSS Modules, react-datepicker-cssmodules.css
// import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-cssmodules.css';

const Picker = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate(); 

    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

    const handleChange = (event) => {
      setStartDate(event.target.value)

      console.log(startDate)
    }

    const handleSubmit = (event) =>{
      event.preventDefault();
      navigate(`/guage/${startDate}`) //upon the call of handleSubmit, a redirect should call the guage component to be rendered, taking the startDate as a URL parameter

    } 
    return (
      <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)} onSelect={handleChange}/>
    );
  };

export default Picker
```

The second problem, is that I need to find a way to input the date selected from the Calendar with the API call to the backend to retrieve the data for my Guage. It only fetches a JSON for now, but the ability to fetch the appropriate JSON per date selected from the Picker.JS component has been giving me a headache.

Here is my DelayGuage.JS code below:

```
import React from "react";
import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";
import axios from "axios";
import {  QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { Link, useLocation, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

async function fetchPosts() {

  const {data} = await axios.get(
    "http://172.16.10.100:5004/reports/{date}/agencies"
  );
  const parsedData = data.agencies[0].kpis.map((r) => [
    "Delay Index",
    r.kpi_value * 100
  ]);

  return [["Label", "Value"], ...parsedData];
}
```

So, to summarize, there are two issues in this project. The first being a way to store the selected date in the datepicker, and the second being a way to parse said selected date in the redirect guage/'${startDate}' URL to be used directly in the API call "http://172.16.10.100:5004/reports/{date}/agencies". This will return a JSON containing the object retrieved from a database (backend has been set up already).

Answer (score 0):

Your `onChange` does the intended behavior of storing the value of the DatePicker input in your state as `startDate`. Passing the `onSelect` prop to the `<DatePicker />` causes issues as the `event` parameter passed in to the `onSelect` is actually just the updated input value (you can see this if you `console.log(event)`). The `<DatePicker />` component is just an input component, not an entire form. You should wrap the component in a form and pass the `handleSubmit` to an `onSubmit` prop of the form. There is an example in the [React Router docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate) for `useNavigate`.

For the second part of your question, look into React Router's url parameters ([guide](https://ui.dev/react-router-url-parameters), [example](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params)). You can use the `useParams()` hook to get the `startDate` from the URL, and use that in your API call.